# No data output from stored procedure (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a basic stored procedure for a select statement. The select statement by itself works and shows me the data output, but when I try calling it from a stored procedure, it says 'CALL Query returned successfully in 107 msec', but there's no data output. Is there something that I'm missing from my stored procedure?
(I'm also connecting a database on AWS with the basic tier, not sure if that makes a difference. Every other CRUD operation works except for select.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
    experiment1()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    SELECT * FROM assignment    
$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Postgres procedure does not return anything. You can use a function instead, with the `return query` syntax. This requires enumerating the columns that the query returns. Assuming that your table has two columns, `id` and `val`, that would be:

```
create function experiment() 
returns table (id int, val text)
as $$
begin
    return query select * from assignment;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

You can then invoke this set-returning function like so:

```
select * from experiment();
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f7b115d55a4db8033bd74beb1d4efa6)**:

```
create table assignment (id int, val text);
insert into assignment values(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar');
-- 2 rows affected

create function experiment() 
returns table (id int, val text)
as $$
begin
    return query select * from assignment;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select * from experiment();
```

```
id | val
-: | :--
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
```

Comment: A SELECT statement inside a stored procedure works but without any issues but I'm wondering why all of a sudden they just stopped for me.